# Define $f(x) = x^6 + x^5 + 3x^4 +x^3 + 3x^2 + x + 1$. Find the largest prime factor of $f(19) + 1$ (Homework)

Tags: polynomials, factoring, prime-factorization

Define $f(x) = x^6 + x^5 + 3x^4 +x^3 + 3x^2 + x + 1$. Find the largest prime factor of $f(19) + 1$ This problem is from a homework set of my class at source: Alphastar.academy. I believe there a number of ways to factor this and solve it, and I would appreciate it if I were able to see a couple methods on how to do this problem.

Comment: Have you tried any of those factoring methods? Remember that you should try to factorize $f(x)+1$ and not $f(x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conveniently, $f(x)+1$ factors as
$$(x^2-x+1)(x^2+x+1)(x^2+x+2)$$
With $x=19$ this produces the three factors $343×381×382$, from which we work out that the largest prime factor is $191$ (of $382$).

Comment: No insight on how it was factorized though?

Comment: @Mourad I just plugged it into SymPy... it's three quadratics, so trial and error with "small" irreducible quadratic polynomials would suffice.